# ffmpeg isn't accepting "%d" format?

Tags: ffmpeg

So, I have a directory full of files named `motor_animate_000.gif`, `motor_animate_001.gif`, etc.

I run:

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -i motor_animate_%03d.gif -r 30 motor.mpg
```

I expect to get a file called `motor.mpg`, but instead I get the usual bunch of printout, ending with:

```
motor_animate_%03d.gif: No such file or directory
```

What?  This worked in Ubuntu 14.04, but doesn't work now.  What I'm doing appears to be consistent with the ffmpeg man page.  I'm now officially clueless.  Thanks in advance.

Here's what I get when I try the alternate suggested below:

```
tim@Servo:~/Documents/Movies/dcmotor/animation$ ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 30 -i motor_animate_%03d.gif motor.mpg
ffmpeg version 2.8.10-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[image2 @ 0x20bd420] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: none, none): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
motor_animate_%03d.gif: could not find codec parameters
Input #0, image2, from 'motor_animate_%03d.gif':
  Duration: 00:00:04.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: none, none, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
No decoder for stream #0:0, filtering impossible
Error opening filters!
```

Answer (score 2):

The [gif demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#gif-1) does not support a series of input files. You'll need to manually tell it to use the [image file demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) instead:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 30 -i motor_animate_%03d.gif motor.mpg
```

- The image file demuxer uses `-framerate` instead of `-r`.
- You don't need to declare frame rate twice if you want to output to be the same as the input, so I removed the output `-r`.

Comment: That got me further.  Now it errors out with "Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: none, none): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
motor_animate_%03d.gif: could not find codec parameters
"

Comment: @TimWescott I'd have to see your actual command and the complete console output to provide any suggestions.

Comment: It won't fit into the comments.

Comment: @TimWescott I didn't intend that you try to fit it into a comment. You can add a link to a pastebin site or edit your question.

Comment: I edited the question -- then forgot to mention that I did.  D'oh.

Comment: @TimWescott Please provide a link to some of the GIF files if possible. Also, try a newer `ffmpeg`: you can download a binary [here](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/).